# MySQL SELECT-query: How can I get the right ID when using the MIN()-function in my query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, min

I'm programming a C# Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio and I'm trying to get data about minimum prices of products in supermarket2 and supermarket 3 from shopping lists.

The first step I need to take is to make a correct SELECT-query that returns this data from my local MySQL-database.

I have the following columns in my prices-table:

- price
- barcode
- supermarket_id

I also have a supermarkets-table which includes 3 supermarkets:

- supermarket_id = 1 NAME = supermarket1
- supermarket_id = 2 NAME = supermarket2
- supermarket_id = 3 NAME = supermarket3

A product has a price for each supermarket in the supermarkets-table

I'm using the following query to let the database return the data I want:

```
SELECT pro.name, MIN(p.price) AS 'Lowest Price', p.supermarket_id
FROM (
    SELECT i.product_barcode
    FROM shopping_list_items i
    WHERE i.shopping_list_id = 95
) s
JOIN prices p ON s.product_barcode = p.barcode
JOIN products pro ON s.product_barcode = pro.barcode
GROUP BY s.product_barcode;
```

**The above query returns the name of the product, the lowest price of the product and the supermarket_id. But the supermarket_id is always 1 although the price of the product is not in supermarket1 but in supermarket3.**

So my question now is how does my query has to be in order to get the supermarket_id along with the minimum price of the products in a specific grocery list

Comment: Ah! The lovely MySQL that runs aggregate queries with missing `GROUP BY` columns where in any other database this very query should fail. Be sure to always turn [ONLY FULL GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode on. Such a mode is a disservice to beginners of SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you should use a `subquery` to get all the barcodes and their minimum prices using `group by and having` clause. And then you can use the resulta to further join with the `prices` table.

```
select p2.price as lowest_price, p2.barcode as prod_barcode , p2.supermarket_id as supermarket from
            (
              select min(price) as min_p, barcode min_b from prices p1 where p1.supermarket_id!=1 group by barcode having barcode in 
              (
                SELECT i.product_barcode FROM shopping_list_items i WHERE i.shopping_list_id = 95
              )
            ) 
    m join prices p2 where m.min_p=p2.price and m.min_b= p2.barcode;
```

Comment: I am assuming that below query provided by you returns single row.

SELECT i.product_barcode FROM shopping_list_items i WHERE i.shopping_list_id = 95

Comment: I copied your previous query, modified it a bit, executed it and the result I am getting is correct but I only want it to calculate the minimum price of supermarket2 and supermarket3. I am now also getting minimum values from supermarket1.

Comment: For that, you can add a where clause on supermarket_id

Comment: supermarket_id is only used in the SELECT-clause I've tried to also use it in the WHERE-clause like WHERE supermarket_id != 1 but when I execute this, it just don't gives me the row back.

Comment: I just modified and checked your updated query:

SELECT p2.barcode, p2.supermarket_id, p2.price AS 'lowest price' FROM
(
SELECT MIN(price) AS min_p, barcode min_b FROM prices p1 GROUP BY barcode HAVING barcode IN 
(
SELECT i.product_barcode FROM shopping_list_items i WHERE i.shopping_list_id = 95
)
) 
m JOIN prices p2 WHERE m.min_p=p2.price AND m.min_b= p2.barcode AND p2.supermarket_id in (2,3)

But this does not return the rows where the cheapest price is at supermarket1

Comment: But you only said in above comment that you do not need for supermarket 1. You only need it for 2 and 3. Can you please clarify what you need.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't explain my self enough for you to understand, I want my query to compare prices of supermarket2 and supermarket3 and give me the lowest price. This means that if a product in supermarket1 is 0.99 and supermarket2 is 1.12 and supermarket3 is 1.45 that I do not want the price from supermarket1 but from supermarket2 because after supermarket1, the price is at its lowest at supermarket2. But when I execute your query, it does not get me the lowest price after supermarket1 but just doesn't return a row if a price is at its lowest at supermarket1.

Comment: Ahh got it. Try below query then.

select p2.price as lowest_price, p2.barcode as prod_barcode , p2.supermarket_id as supermarket from ( select min(price) as min_p, barcode min_b from prices p1 where p1.supermarket_id!=1 group by barcode having barcode in ( SELECT i.product_barcode FROM shopping_list_items i WHERE i.shopping_list_id = 95 ) ) m join prices p2 where m.min_p=p2.price and m.min_b= p2.barcode ;

Answer (score 1):

Consider this adjusted aggregate query with correct `GROUP BY` clause which resolves the OP's need:

> to get the supermarket_id along with the minimum price of the products in a specific grocery list

```
SELECT p.supermarket_id, 
       pro.name as product_name, 
       MIN(p.price) AS 'Lowest Price'
FROM (
    SELECT i.product_barcode
    FROM shopping_list_items i
    WHERE i.shopping_list_id = 95
) s
JOIN prices p ON s.product_barcode = p.barcode
JOIN products pro ON s.product_barcode = pro.barcode
GROUP BY p.supermarket_id, 
         pro.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name, pr.lowest_price, p.supermarket_id,s.supermarket_name from 
products p INNER JOIN
(SELECT barcode,supermarket_id,MIN(price) as AS 'lowest_price'
FROM prices
GROUP BY barcode,supermarket
)pr on pr.barcode = p.barcode
INNER JOIN supermarkets s on pr.supermarket_id = s.supermarket_id
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your answer but this query does not work, I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: Can you please check now? Apparently there was some mismatch in aliases for the tables